# Difference between bode and freqz

Tags: matlab

I am creating a filter in MATLAB like so:

```
[num,den] = ellip(10,0.1,50,4000/22050,'high');
```

Using **freqz** I then found the frequency response of the filter like so:

```
freqz(num,den)
```

This produces as expected a high pass filter plot. However, if I try to plot the same set of values using the **bode** function I get something entirely different.

```
bode(tr(num,den))
```

This produces a low pass filter plot. Am I not understanding how these functions work? It was my understanding that freqz took the coefficients of a transfer function as its arguments. This is also what I am doing with the bode function.

Why the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[b,a] = ellip(n,Rp,Rs,Wp)
```

where `b,a` are z-domain representatives,

[image]

while `tf` by default is for s-domain:

you can use `filt` instead,

```
[b,a] = ellip(10,0.1,50,4000/22050,'high');
freqz(b,a) 
figure
bode(filt(b,a))
```

You can also use `bode(tf(b,a,-1,'variable','z^-1'))`.

Check the `variable property` for `tf`.

> String specifying the transfer function display variable. Variable can take the following values:
>
> 's' — Default for continuous-time models
>
> 'z' — Default for discrete-time models
>
> 'p' — Equivalent to 's'
>
> 'q' — Equivalent to 'z'
>
> 'z^-1' — Inverse of 'z'
>
> 'q^-1' — Equivalent to 'z^-1'